# Can I rewrite a datetime64 column in a dataframe to just show the time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have two columns (Length approx 150) in my dataframe named 'Sleep' and 'Wake' which look like this:

```
Sleep            |   Wake      
8/4/2020 0:04    |   8/4/2020 6:30
```

Can I rewrite these columns to show only the time, while keeping it in the datetime64[ns] format? This is primarily for tidying my data.

Comment: No, I think not. What you could do is create separate columns with only the time, but those would then be of dtype object.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Sleep_day'] = [d.date() for d in df['Sleep']]
df['Sleep_time'] = [d.time() for d in df['Sleep']]
df['Wake_day'] = [d.date() for d in df['Wake']]
df['Wake_time'] = [d.time() for d in df['Wake']]
```

or:

```
df = df.assign(Sleep_day=df.Sleep.dt.date, Sleep_time=df.Sleep.dt.time, Wake_day=df.Wake.dt.date, Wake_time=df.Wake.dt.time)
```